# How to get columns from duplicated rows in Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows

I'm trying to get columns in my data set from rows.
Here is my present DataFrame:

[DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J58xi.png)

What I want to achieve, is convert the following rows from column of index 0:

> title:, category:, ..., href:

into columns without duplicates (there would be 7 columns) and match the corresponding rows from column of index 1 to them.

[Column 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nB1j1.png)

I've tried to transpose this dataframe, but i didn't know how to reduce amount of columns.

Code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=items)
df_2 = df.transpose()
```

Output:

[Transposed DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bouKx.png)

What I've also tried:

```
pd.set_index(), pd.groupby(), pd.reset_index()
```

but it didn't work either.

Thank you so much for Your help. Have a nice day!

Comment: Welcome to SO, please avoid adding images instead see here about creating [`reproducible-pandas-examples`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/4985099)

Comment: what output you are expecting?

Comment: Thank You for the answer. I will remember to avoid adding images!

Comment: @deadshot take rows title, etc and match to rows from image named Column 1

Comment: From your image it is very hard to understand.So pleas create some example data not image(Input and desired output)

Comment: I think what you are looking for is called pivoting in analytics. Checkout df.pivot() in pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this**

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["title", "hp"],["category", "Laptop"], ["price", 30000], ["title", "lenovo"],["category", "Laptop"], ["price", 40000]],columns=["label", "value"])

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
      label      value
 0    title       hp
 1    category    Laptop
 2    price       30000
 3    title      lenovo
 4    category   Laptop
 5    price      40000
```

**strong text**

```
 label = df["label"].unique()
 a = df.groupby('label')
 df1 = pd.DataFrame()
 for i in label:
     df1[i] = list(a.get_group(i)['value'])

 print(df1)
```

**Output**

```
     title    category  price
 0   hp       Laptop    30000
 1   lenovo   Laptop    40000
```

Not sure what you are looking for.But this could help you